# jQuery - Target button with enter key when input field is focused

Tags: jquery, html

I have an input field and a login button.  I want to allow users to hit the "enter" key to click the button when the input field is focused.  How would I do this with jQuery?

```
<input type="text" size="10" id="loginUserID" name="username">
<input type="button" value="Login" name="loginBtn" id="loginBtn">
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
$('#loginUserID').keypress(function(event){
  if(event.keyCode == 13){
    $('#loginBtn').click();
  }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Bhf5a/

Comment: More general way is `$(this).keypress(function(event){ ...`. Then it captures the `ENTER` key for all input objects.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need jQuery for this, just change the button to `type="submit"`:

```
<input type="text" size="10" id="loginUserID" name="username">
<input type="submit" value="Login" name="loginBtn" id="loginBtn">
```

Then the `<form>` will submit all by itself when you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> inside the text input.

Comment: What if he has another listener on the button click and not the form submit?

Comment: @Alien: Then he could have a problem and he'd have to do it by hand like you did. Hard to tell what's up given that small HTML snippet.

Answer (score 7):

If they're in the same form and you change the button to be `type="submit"` you should find it happens automatically, but anyway...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('#loginUserID').keypress(function(e){
      if(e.which === 13)
         $('#loginBtn').click();
   });

});
```

(Or you may prefer `.keyup` or `.keydown`.)

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer, and most of the others, give for granted that the click() action might end event handling by submitting the form and switching to another page, or that there is not a submit somewhere on the form, so they omit stopping the event chain, but this might not be the case.

Don't forget to call `e.preventDefault()` before calling `click()` on the target button. Or else, the first button on the form will still fire on enter, in addition to your click!

```
$('#loginUserID').keypress(function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Stop the default behaviour
        $('#loginBtn').click();
    }
});
```

Comment: It's not an answer to the question.

Comment: While it's not an answer to the question, it gives the other answers as granted and it shows they are all wrong (in a way). If you don't put `e.preventDefault()` you will still get the default behaviour of hitting RETURN inside a field after the emulated click, and that might be a problem. It should have been a comment below every single answer, or it could cite the other answers and add the complete code, but it is useful and necessary...

Answer (score -2):

The answer does not work when the trigger is somewhere attached in asp.net code adn not in js or jquery. What works fine is setting the focus on the button. In your case replace my named (sharepoint generated) fields with your login fields

```
    <script type ="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var zoekveld = $( "input[name='ctl00$m$g_02abe20b_56ca_4744_a694_5bc31dd14f49$ctl02']" );
        var loep = $( "input[name='ctl00$m$g_02abe20b_56ca_4744_a694_5bc31dd14f49$ctl04']" );
        zoekveld.keypress(function(e){
            //alert("gevonden op name");
            var key = e.which;
            if(key == 13){
                 //alert("op enter geklikt");
                  loep.focus();
             }
        });         
    });
 </script>
```